# How to set NLog's internal LogFile programmatically for dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog, programmatic-config

I know you can set NLog's internal log file programmatically like this:

```cs
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = @"C:\Logs\nlog.log";
```

The above trick does not work for the following scenario, where I need to be able to set internal log file that's used by injected NLog.  The one that gets created inside ASP.NET Core WebApi, using the following

```cs
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
   logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
})
.UseNLog();
```

Are there any workarounds for me to programmatically configure LogFile and LogLeve of the NLog object that gets dependency injected?

Comment: How exactly is setting `NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile` in your case not working? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which show the problem you have with `NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile`. And how is the internal logger relevant for you when using an injectect `NLog` instance?

Comment: 1. It's not working, because it gets overriden by the "NLog.{ASP_NET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT}.config that I'm guessing is wired up by .UseNLog() extension function.
2. Internal log is relevant, because I want to be able to be able to output NLog internal errors to the file I specify.

Comment: @Eternal21 Why not just remove `internalLogFile="..."` from `NLog.{ASP_NET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT}.config` ? Or just re-assign `InternalLogger.LogFile` after having called `LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()` ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen Your first suggestion worked.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove `internalLogFile="..."` from `NLog.{ASP_NET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT}.config` ?

Or just re-assign `InternalLogger.LogFile` after having called `LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()` ?